# Generalized is() type-checking function for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, classes

In a complex library I've been working on, I got pretty tired of all of the individual type functions and operators to determine whether I was working with an object or piece of data of a given type. This was especially true when I was checking for inherited prototypes between classes. In an effort to alleviate, I made this generalized is() function.

```
( function( root ) {
    var is = function( v, t ) {
        if ( typeof v !== 'undefined' ) {
            if ( typeof t === 'string' )
                return typeof v === t;
            else if ( typeof t === 'function' ) {
                if ( typeof v === 'object' )
                    return v instanceof t;
                else if ( typeof v === 'function' )
                    return t.prototype.isPrototypeOf( v.prototype );
                else return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    root['is'] = is;
}( this ) );
```

**Syntax**

- `is(variable, type)` where type is any return from `typeof`

  - returns true if `variable` typeof === `type`
- `is(variable, class)` where variable is an object and class is a constructor

  - returns true if `variable` is an instanceof `class`
- `is(class1, class2)` where class is a constructor and class is a constructor

  - returns true if `class1`'s prototype is a descendant of `class2`'s prototype.

**Usage**

I use this function whenever the type of a value is imperative. One common example is when I need different behaviors depending on the type. As an example:

```
// typeof myVar === 'number'
if(is(myVar,'number')) {       
    doSomething();
}
//      myVar instanceof Array
elseif (is(myVar,Array)) {     
    doSomethingWithArray();
}
//      typeof myVar === 'object'
elseif (is(myVar,'object')) {  
    doSomethingWithObject();
}
```

**Reasons for this function**

The goal is to reduce the amount of `typeof`, `instanceof` and `isPrototypeOf` statements, as well as the need for individualized type checking methods. This certainly seems to accomplish much of that goal. A nice little beneficial side effect is that it reduces the code of using libraries significantly. I've been utilizing it in some newer libraries (at a minified overhead of 150 bytes) and it has saved me much more than that, as well as an uncountable number of keystrokes.

**Reason for this Question**

While I haven't noticed a performance hit, I would like a review with more quantifiable statistics. Additionally, should I have special handling for falsey values? Are there other gotchas that I'm not accounting for?

Here is the minified code:

```
(function(c){c['is']=function(a,b){if("undefined"!==typeof a){if("string"===typeof b)return typeof a===b;if("function"===typeof b){if("object"===typeof a)return a instanceof b;if("function"===typeof a)return b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a.prototype)}}return !1}})(this);
```

**Update: Performance**

After performing some of the suggested changes, since no one addressed performance, I took some time and learned me some jsPerf. The switch/case variant, performed much more slowly than the if/else variant. Further, I made another variant using the ternary (?) operator which performed much better. [Here is the test.](http://jsperf.com/is-switch-vs-is-ternary-vs-operators)

Since type-checking is generally quick and fairly uncommon compared to many other operations, I'm certainly willing to take the hit.

**Update: Revised Code (using comments and answer)**

```
( function( root ) {
// To force minifiers to ignore function name
    root['is'] = function(value, type) {
        if ('undefined' !== typeof value) {
            switch (typeof type) {
            case 'string':
                return typeof value === type;
            case 'function':
                switch (typeof value) {
                case 'object':
                    return value instanceof type;
                case 'function':
                // Account for default behavior
                    return type === Function 
                         ? true 
                         : type.prototype.isPrototypeOf(value.prototype);
                }
            }
        }
    // Account for passed undefined values
        return ('undefined' === t) 
             ? true
             : false;
    };
}( this ) );
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how this code would be used in practice? Usually, JavaScript programmers don't encounter the `is(v, t)` problem because [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is the norm.

Comment: Added in edit above

Comment: I know this is intentional behavior, but consider whether you want `is(v, Array)` to return `true` when `v` is an array, but `is(v, Function)` to return `false` when `v` is a function and `is(v, Number)` to return `false` when `v` is a primitive number. (`is(v, 'function')` and `is(v, 'number')` work correctly, though.) Also, `is(v, 'undefined')` can never return `true`.

Comment: There is no way to resolve is(v,'undefined') as calling v when it is undefined results in an runtime error. The others, however, I should consider, thank you.

Comment: @icktoofay is behavior different between 'function' and Function, or between 'number' and Number?

Comment: After checking the various debuggers, a function does validate as an instanceof Function, and [] does validate as an instanceof Array. Since this is default behavior, I shall not change it, as it should be expected. 32 is not a Number, however, and am not sure how/if I will address that, yet. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code Review

### Coding Style

You coding style is quite uncommon. However, it is fine if it is consistent across
your projects.

My personal preference is to use constant ahead of comparison so it looks a
little bit less confusing:

```
if ('function' === typeof v)
```

Anyway, in this particular case it is sematically better to use `switch` so it
emphasises that the variable is immutable within the statement:

```
switch (typeof t) {
case 'string':
    return t === typeof v;
case 'function':
    ...
}
```

Some style guides also recommend to remove redundant `else` after `return`. This
will decrease indentation and simplify the code statements.

It is better to use a little bit descriptive variable names. For example,
`type` instead of `t` and `value` instead of `v`.

You can elliminate the variable `is` by assigning the function directly to
root's property. Or there is a special preference to keep the variable `is`?

### Logic

It is doubtful whether this function should return `false` for
`is(undefined, 'undefined')`. It looks like it is a completely valid check that
will fail.

If the argument value is not supported, it may be better to throw an exception
instead of returning plausible value. For example, `is(null, null)` will return
false, but `null` is just not supported value of the parameter `t`.

I understand that it contradicts a little with an original purpose of the function
but it looks like this usage of the function may be quite handy.

Please also be aware of multi-instance environment. If Array object created
within one vm instance (or iframe), `instanceof Array` will fail. You can find
more examples here: http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/

### Revised Code

```
(function (root) {
    root.is = function (value, type) {
        if ('undefined' !== typeof value) {
            switch (typeof type) {
            case 'string':
                return type === typeof value;
            case 'function':
                switch (typeof value) {
                case 'object':
                    return value instanceof type;
                case 'function':
                    return type.prototype.isPrototypeOf(value.prototype);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}(this));
```

BTW, its minified version is 8 bytes shorter (with closure-compiler)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Some notes: I never feel uncomfortable looking at other projects. I've been doing this for 20 years, but am new simply to JS. Regarding `undefined, 'undefined'` I shall amend that because it is valid. `null, null`, I do agree, should probably return an exception. What do you mean about your statement on Arrays? could you elaborate or give a use case? Regarding variable names, understood. I often use descriptive unless it is painfully obvious, and when it isn't supportive doc (like above) is always provided. Thanks again!

Comment: One note: is it preferrable to use `switch/case` when there are only two cases? I've often leaned toward `if/else` with few cases. I'd like to see if some other pipe in, but this is a handy candidate for an accepted answer if you can elaborate on the Arrays in multi-instance environment.

Comment: I'm sorry for the first statement. Just corrected it. As for Array here is an example: http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/ You may do not use the function `is` in this way, of course, so it is fine now, but it is very interesting aspect of the `instanceof`. As for `switch` it is, of course, very subjective, but there is at least one important drawback of `if` in such case: the value should be calculated twice so it is a code duplication. Very small, but here it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. I would still prefer that you place it in your answer, but this is certainly good enough for an accepted answer. While your switch does not perform well for this function, your justification regarding usage is sound. I will be providing edits as I gather more information, I encourage you to do the same should you feel the need.